# PythonのdatetimeオブジェクトからUnix Timeを求める

Tags: python

Unixタイムを、特定のタイムゾーンでの日時(datetimeオブジェクト)に変換するには、

```
import datetime
import pytz
unix_time = 123456789.123456
dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(unix_time, pytz.timezone('America/Los_Angeles'))
```

のようにすればできます。

逆に、このようなdatetimeオブジェクトからunixタイムを計算するにはどのような方法が簡単でしょうか?
(上記の例では、`dt`から、UNIXタイム `123456789.123456`をなるべく簡単に求めたい。)

計算するマシンのタイムゾーンがなんであっても正しく動くアプローチが望ましいです。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

元の`unix_time`の秒数を知りたいということでしたら

```
>>> import calendar
>>> calendar.timegm(dt.astimezone(pytz.utc).timetuple())
123456789
```

および

```
>>> dt.microsecond
123456
```

とできます。

Comment: なるほど。一度タイムゾーンをUTCに変換してから計算するということですね。`calendar`モジュールは使わざるおえないのでしょうか....

Answer (score 3):

Python3では、

```python
>>> dt.timestamp()
123456789.123456
```

でタイムスタンプを取得できます。

Python2にはtimestamp()メソッドがないので、素直にエポックを定数として持っておいて

```python
>>> EPOCH = datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, tzinfo=pytz.timezone('utc'))
>>> (dt - EPOCH).total_seconds()
123456789.123456
```

がお手軽ではないでしょうか。ちなみに、Python3のdatetime.timestamp()の実装も、上のようになっています。

Comment: こちらも参考にしてください。 naive (tzinfo がない) な UTC の datetime を扱う場合などについても書いています。
http://qiita.com/methane/items/d7ac3c9af5a2c659bc51

Comment: これがPythonの標準的なやりかたです。

Answer (score 1):

ミリ秒の単位が要らないのであれば、

```
>>> import os
>>> import time
>>> os.environ['TZ'] = 'UTC'
>>> time.mktime(dt.utctimetuple())
>>> 123456789.0
```

環境変数をいじるので、Linuxでしか確認していないです。